# ASP.NET MVC how to repointing to a new table in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have built a simple website for updating data in a table.
1) now I wanted to change the table name in the C# project. Table structure is same. Where should I do this?
2) the new table doesn't have primary key. Is it mandatory for the website to work?

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: 1) How did you create the table to begin with? You probably need to use a similar tool/process to update it. 2) no it's not. But you should read about what primary keys are and why they are used, and then make a decision. As a generalisation most tables either benefit from having one or are, at the very least not hindered by doing so.

Comment: sorry. didnt make it clear. I wanted to change the name in my C# project, so that its pointing to my new table existing in sql server

Comment: "change the name in my C# project"...please be more specific. What kind of naming are we talking about currently? Do you have an Entity Framework model perhaps? Or some other kind of method of connecting to the database?

Comment: I want to change the table name in my ASP.NET mvc project. The table name i used was AAA, and after i renamed it as BBB in sql server, I need to update the new table name in my ASP.NET MVC project as well

Comment: When i initially built the project, I created a ADO.NET Entity Data Model for connecting to the database

Comment: So I guess that generated an EDMX file? If so, you can update it easily and it will auto-generate new code based on the updated database structure. Here is a guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-update-an-edmx-file-using-entity-framework-data-model-in-visual-stud/ , look for the section called "Update the .edmx file when the Database changes"

Comment: thanks much. yes thats what im looking for. but i dont see the option when right click the .edmx on my project. i added a pic here

Comment: Follow the tutorial more closely. You have to double click on the edmx, which opens the diagram showing the tables (this is what is known as the "model browser"). Then right click anywhere in an empty space on that diagram and the option should appear

Answer (score 0):

If it's SQL server, you can run an internal sp called `sp_rename` like so:

```
USE MyDataBase;   
GO  
EXEC sp_rename 'OldTableName', 'NewTableName';
```

Or you can do it via SSMS as outlined here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-tables-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I wanted to change the name in my C# project, so that its pointing to my new table existing in sql server